# Confusion on match_parent and wrap_content between parent and children element in xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

[image]

In line 4,in the parent tag the `android:layout_width` has been set to `wrap_content.` But in the child tags, the `android:layout_width` has been set to `match_parent.` Then what is the meaning of `match_parent` for the child tags when the parent tag itself has just the width to `wrap_content`.

My straight-forward question maybe is that, why the child tags cover up the whole screen when they must agree to the `wrap_content` attribute of the parent tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just an error of the xml viewer, I've put the code in android studio and it just work fine. If you use "wrap_content" for width and height in the parent layout every child with "match_parent" for width and hight will be large and tall as the parent. I just modify the first child but it is the same for the others.

[image]

Comment: This means that child width layout depends on parent tag and not the screen when we set attribute value to match_parent. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Thank You! Please answer my above question.

Comment: If you set the width on parent to wrap_content and the child on match parent yes. As in the example i did above. You are welcome